# Popup Recommends Adding A Comment When Comments are Locked

Tags: feature-request

I recently voted on a meta question.  Comments for the question were locked at the time.  Nevertheless, a popup suggested I consider adding a comment to explain my vote.

This popup probably should not appear when comments are locked.